# Помогите пожалуйста решить задание

Tags: c, ряды

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста написать код для решения зависимости y от x, которые изменяются в диапазоне от x начального до х конечного с шагом дельта х.
Надо чтобы выводило массив хі  yi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
main ()
{
    int k, x;
    float y;
    scanf ("%d", &x);
    for (k=1; k<=5; k++)
     y+= (3/5)*(pow ((k+2), 1/3))/(cos (2*x)*cos(2*x)-1);
     printf ("%f", y);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Неизменную (не зависящую от индекса) часть выносите за сумму. Пишете цикл от 1 до 5, в нем суммируете переменную часть. Умножаете на вынесенное, выводите...

Comment: `3/5` -> `3./5`. И с `1/3` аналогично.

Answer (score 2):

Можно и так, как вы написали, но только `(3/5)` - это *целочисленное* деление, дает 0. Пишите 3./5., или просто 0.6 :) Равно как и 1/3. А еще - почему x у вас целое? А y - не инициализировано?...

Словом, вот так будет лучше:

```
int main ()
{
    int k;
    double x, y = 0;
    scanf ("%lf", &x);
    for (k=1; k<=5; k++)
        y+= pow(k+2, 1./3.);
    double z = cos(2*x);
    y *= 0.6/(z*z-1);

    printf ("%lf\n", y);
}
```

Comment: Выдавало - из-за 3/5 == 0... См., например - https://ideone.com/cFf8ZL